# looping over each line of a file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm wondering how you can loop over each line of a file heres the code I have so far:

```
FILE *todoFile;
todoFile = fopen("./todo.txt", "r");

if (todoFile != NULL) {

} else {
    printf("ERROR");
}
```

Comment: Have you investigated writing a regular expression evaluator?  Or a library?  If so, Which ones?  We are not here to do your work for you.  Only to help you with a little nudge when you get stuck.

Comment: I can figure out the regular expressions myself, just the main thing is how to loop over each line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idiomatic way to read a file line-by-line until it ends is

```
    /* assume line is a char array */
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, handle)) {
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        if (len && (line[len - 1] != '\n')) {
            /* incomplete line */
        }
        /* possibly remove trailing newline ... and */
        /* deal with line */
    }
```

Comment: What should `line` be? (sorry I'm really new to C)

Comment: @errorhandler usually a `char` array, like `char line[100];` As @pmg says in his comments above the while loop.

Comment: `char line[500];` define line with space for lines up to 499 characters long: remember that *'strings'*, in C, include a terminating null byte.

Comment: Hmmm ... if you don't know how long lines can be (and there isn't a reasonable upper limit) you need to forget about the char array and use dynamic memory with `malloc` and `realloc` memory (or use a non-standard function like `getline()`).

Comment: This is weak. Why not use `getline()`?

Comment: `getline` does have a downside: if it exhausts memory before finding a newline, there is no way to recover the partially-read line. There's also no way to keep it from hogging all memory on malicious input...

Comment: So what should I use getline or just fgets, when I say I don't know how long the line will be its not going to be *very* long I suppose I could have a limit like 256 or something like that

Comment: @errorhandler: set your line limit to something like 4096 (not a measly and easily exceeded 256). POSIX [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_24) sets a limit, LINE_MAX, and the minimum permitted value for that is _POSIX2_LINE_MAX, which is the value 2048.  How many GiB of main memory does your machine have?  It won't notice 4 KiB!